# Run resharper silent cleanup on save fails

Tags: resharper, code-cleanup, visual-studio-macros

I'm trying to clean up my code on save using Resharper's Cleanup Code function. I made a macro that handles `DocumentSaved` events. The important parts:

```
Private Sub DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved(ByVal document As EnvDTE.Document) _
                                         Handles DocumentEvents.DocumentSaved
    ...
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode")
    document.Save()
End Sub
```

Every time I save, I get an exception message that says `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.` Any ideas?

Note: I see [How can I configure ReSharper's code cleanup on save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071953/how-can-i-configure-resharpers-code-cleanup-on-save) and it won't work in my situation because I need to respond to the save event. Mapping a macro to CTRL+S isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when you call `document.Save()` it is recursing and saving again and then it falls over.  Try this:

```
Private Sub DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved(ByVal Document As EnvDTE.Document) Handles DocumentEvents.DocumentSaved
    Static currentDocument As EnvDTE.Document

    If Not currentDocument Is Document Then
        currentDocument = Document
        DTE.Windows.Item(Document.Name).Activate()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode")
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Save()
    End If
End Sub
```

This worked for me